# Child MenuItems are not expanding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, controls

I have a simple popup control that holds multiple `MenuItem`'s in it.

```
<Popup
    IsOpen="{Binding ShowPopupMenu}"
    <StackPanel Background="White">
        <ItemsControl>
            <MenuItem Header="Open file..." />
            <MenuItem Header="Settings" />
            
            <!-- Nested items -->
            <MenuItem Header="Test">
                <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
            </MenuItem>
            
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" />
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

My problem is that `MenuItem` with header `Test`, that contains nested childrens is not expanding on mouse over.

I'm actually able to see it expanding in the design time

[image],

However, when it's simply not working on runtime.

Any ideas why is that?

Comment: Can you show the code in question that maybe of help to us to help you.

Comment: Why not use a menu?

Comment: @EdPlunkett How is that different?

Comment: @DonaldDuck It works.

Comment: @EdPlunkett You're very kind and helpful. This site definitely needs more people like you.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Is that sarcasm? MenuItems work properly when they are children of a menu. Used as you did, they don’t work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is that the Popup control handles mouse click event and, therefore, it does not reaches your menu item, try opening it manually by handling `PreviewLeftButton` event:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Panel">
    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Panel}" 
        IsOpen="True">
        <StackPanel Background="White">
            <!--<Menu>-->
                <MenuItem Header="Open file..." />
                <MenuItem Header="Settings" />

                <!-- Nested items -->
                <MenuItem Header="Test" Click="MenuItem_OnClick" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem Header="Exit" />
            <!--</Menu>-->
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

And:

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((MenuItem)sender).IsSubmenuOpen = true;
}
```

**EDIT**

My mistake, the problem is not related with the Click event not being handled. I just put a button in the stackpanel and it worked. The problem is that when a MenuItem has subitems the click event is not fired and one must manually handled the state of the submenu if the root menu item is not "child" of either a `Menu` or a `ContextMenu` control. Those controls handle that already, but since you are implementing your own "ContextMenu" then you must implement that behavior by yourself

Comment: Why not use triggers then?

Comment: @DonaldDuck I do not know how that could be achieved. In order to define such a trigger you need to hook up to a property in Test MenuItem, some `IsMousePressedOver` property, but, unfortunately such a property does not exist. A more reusable approach would be to define a custom behavior.

Comment: I think that submenu expands on hover, so in that case perhaps something like that? https://pastebin.com/MyPy3Gip

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Style` with a `Trigger` that sets the `IsSubmenuOpen` property to `true`:

```
<Popup IsOpen="True">
    <StackPanel Background="White">
        <ItemsControl>
            <MenuItem Header="Open file..." />
            <MenuItem Header="Settings" />

            <!-- Nested items -->
            <MenuItem Header="Test">
                <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                <MenuItem Header="Nested Item" />
                <MenuItem.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="True" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.Style>
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem Header="Exit" />
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

Comment: I've just tried this solution, as said in the comments to the other answer. The only issue with that is, when you are moving the mouse at expanded submenu and hit at the [spacing](https://i.imgur.com/qtLXBr4.png) between submenu and the popup, the submenu will close.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: How come there is a space? You didn't mention this in your original question.

Comment: No idea, perhaps a default style? I haven't been overriding anything.

Comment: Is there enough space to display the sub menu to the right?

Comment: No, since the popup appear in the upper-right corner of the application, the submenu appear on the left side of the popup.